# Finding a value in boost unordered_map object

Tags: c++11, boost

I am trying to find a value in unordered_map as following:

```
#include <boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using namespace std;

typedef int     ApplicationID;
typedef address IPAddress;
typedef list <ApplicationID> APP_LIST;
typedef boost::unordered::unordered_map <IPAddress, APP_LIST> USER_MAP;

USER_MAP user_map;

void function_name()
{
    std::pair<IPAddress*, std::size_t> user_ip = managed_shm->find<IPAddress>("USER-IP"); 
    USER_MAP::const_iterator got = user_map.find(user_ip.first);
}
```

But I get the following error in the find command if user_map:

```
ipc_module.cpp:147:75: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::unordered::unordered_map<boost::asio::ip::address, std::list<int> >::find(boost::asio::ip::address*&)’
```

So what's the problem, in find?

**New Edit:**

Now I've new problem, after modifications which is when I use the iterator to get the associated list as folllowing:

```
        USER_MAP::iterator got = user_map.find(*user_ip);
        if (got == user_map.end())
        {}
        else
        {
            APP_LIST list = (APP_LIST) got->second;
            list->push_front(*app_id);
        }
```

But I get the following error:

```
 ipc_module.cpp:162:25: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘APP_LIST {aka std::list<int>}’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your defined hash map, you use the following key-value pair:

```
unordered_map <IPAddress, APP_LIST> USER_MAP;
```

which means the key type of this hash map is `IPAddress`. But when you use the member function of `find()`, the supplied argument is `user_ip.first` which by your definition is of type `IPAddress*` since you defined

```
std::pair<IPAddress*, std::size_t> user_ip
```

Therefore the compiler reports error because it expects `boost::asio::ip::address*&` as the input argument. From the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html), the `find()` method has the following signature:

```
const_iterator find(key_type const&) const;
```

So to correct it, you can define the pair `user_ip` to take the first item to be of type `IPAddress`:

```
std::pair<IPAddress, std::size_t> user_ip;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I did modifications now I've new problem. Could you help me?

Comment: What's the new problem?

Comment: Your `APP_LIST` is basically `list<ApplicationID>`, so when you call `push_front()` method of `list`, you need to put `ApplicationID` type. Also, `list` is not a pointer but a variable. So you need to use `a.b()` syntax, not `a->b()`. I guess it should be `list.push_front(app_id)` if `app_id` is of `ApplicationID` type.